# Grails, how can I respond with an error, to an AJAX-call, from the controller

Tags: ajax, grails

I have an AJAX function that is invoked when I click on a checkbox. Normally it switches on or off a part of my page. That works good, but when an error occurs, ie. when in certain situations it is not allowed to click the checkbox, I want to inform AJAX that this was not successful.

I also don't know how to fix the error message to show up in the same place that the flash-message use.

If I use the flash-message I need to redirect to the same page again and then I get the page inside itself and that's not so nice.

Im sure that ther should exist a standrd solution to this b'cause I think it's a common case or...?

This is how the part of the controller that is used in this case:

```
def useWeeklyVolumes() {
    println("useWeeklyVolumes - params: "+params)
    def od = OfferDetail.get(params.id)
    String status =  od.offerHeader.status 
    if ((status == 'Sold') || (status == 'Rejected')) {
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        return render(status: 400, text:"Offer can not be changed (Sold/Rejected)")            
    }
```

And here is how the AJAX-call looks like.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( document ).on('change', '.useWeeklyVolumes', function ( event ){ 
            $.ajax({
                url: '${g.createLink( controller:'offerDetail', action:'useWeeklyVolumes' )}',
                data: {ckbWeeklyVolumes:this.checked, id:this.id},
                type: 'get',
                success: function ( data ) { $( '#nono' ).html( data );     },
                error: function (jqXHR) {document.querySelector('#alert').innerHTML = jqXHR.responseText;
                            const timeoutID = window.setTimeout(() => {
                            messageBox.innerHTML = '';
                            window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
                }, 3000);}
            });
        });
    });
```

This is my latest attempt:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( document ).on('change', '.batman', function ( event ){ 
        alert('Hej');
            $.ajax({
                url: '${g.createLink( controller:'person', action:'register' )}',
                data: {registered:this.checked, id:this.id},
                type: 'get',
                success: function ( data ) { $( '#alert' ).html( data );     },
                error: function (jqXHR) {const alert = document.querySelector('#alert').innerHTML = jqXHR.responseText;
                        const timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function() {
                        alert.innerHTML = '';
                        window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
                }, 3000);}
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

in the gsp I added this:

```
<span id="alert"></span>
```

The error message displays here but it'll remain there until I do a refresh.

The final solution:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( document ).on('change', '.batman', function ( event ){ 
                $.ajax({
                    url: '${g.createLink( controller:'person', action:'register' )}',
                    data: {registered:this.checked, id:this.id},
                    type: 'get',
                    success: function ( data ) { $( '#alert' ).html( data );     },
                    error: function (jqXHR) {const alert = document.querySelector('#alert');
                        alert.innerHTML = jqXHR.responseText;
                        const timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function() {
                            alert.innerHTML = '';
                            window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

An alternate solution with a separate error function:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( document ).on('change', '.batman', function ( event ){ 
                $.ajax({
                    url: '${g.createLink( controller:'person', action:'register' )}',
                    data: {registered:this.checked, id:this.id},
                    type: 'get',
                    success: function ( data ) { $( '#alert' ).html( data );     },
                    error: function (jqXHR) {displayAlertMessage(jqXHR.responseText)}
                });
            });
        });


        function displayAlertMessage(message) {
            var timeOut = 5
            jQuery('#alert').text(message).fadeIn()
            jQuery('#alert').css("display", "block")
            setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('#alert').fadeOut()
            jQuery('#alert').css("display", "none")
            }, timeOut * 1000);
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: so when you say error you mean you're dealing with a situation in the controller action & want to relay a message to the flash area, not an unexpected error?

Comment: Yes, say for instance that the status of the offer is: "rejected", then I want to respond with an error message that would display in the flash.message area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to display an error message in the same div where the flash message is displayed and assuming the div has the alert id, you could do something like this

```
// Remember jquery ajax error function can accept this params
// Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
const alert = document.querySelector('#alert');

alert.innertHTML = 'Some message';

const timeoutID = window.setTimeout(() => {
       alert.innerHTML = '';
       window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}, 3000);
```

This should go into the error function which accepts up to three parameters as shown in the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

This will display a message that you get from data and after 3 seconds it will delete it.

As @bassmartin mentions you can in the controller use the [render](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html) method to create a specific message and define states. Or if you use a grails version higher than 2.3 you can use [respond](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/respond.html).

On the first version that uses respond I am not very clear, first read the documentation of your version if you decide to go for that option

Comment: That looks very interesting, but I failed to include it in the error function.

Comment: I did like this: error: function(data){your code} and if I put the div id somewhere else I get the text like: "object Object" And the text will not fade away.

Comment: I changed to use jqXHR.responseText instead of Data and then I get the text but still, the text does not disappear.

Comment: I am trying to recreate your scenario, in order to figure out what is wrong, when done i come back

Comment: I just updated my answer, i changed messageBox for an alert variable

Comment: check this jsfiddle for a live example https://jsfiddle.net/jd9zf4mo/ this will print the success scenario. Change the url to get the error scenario

Comment: Everything works as expected but the text will never disappear. I added my translated version of your example. Check if I did something wrong. I've been testing a lot of versions now.

Comment: My mistake in the example i shared is that `alert` must be equal to a `document.querySelector('#alert')`. I fixed check the example. The same problem is in your code

Comment: Good! :) I have also found another solution, it works exactly the same but your is shorter. Thank's!

Answer (score 2):

You call `render` with your text message and a status code of 400 so your javascript 'error:' code is executed.
http://docs.grails.org/3.1.x/ref/Controllers/render.html